# Retrieve a json element without knowing the name

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object like this :

```
var saveChamp = {
      "champ1": {"type": "radio", "size": 4, "null": null},
      "champ2": {"type": 3, "size": 4, "null": null}
    };

alert(saveChamp.champ1.type);
```

In this example, alert display "radio", it's normal.

How can i do if i don't know champ1 or champ2 for retrieve "type" or "size" ? I create my json dynamically so i can't know all name of my objects.

Thanks you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `for ... in` syntax, to retrieve all elements of an objects, whose name you don't know in before ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)).

Note the `hasOwnProperty()` clause ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty)). This prevents JavaScript from going up in the prototype chain and only work on properties of the object itself. So you wont get the default methods of `Object` for example.

```
var saveChamp = {
      "champ1": {"type": "radio", "size": 4, "null": null},
      "champ2": {"type": 3, "size": 4, "null": null}
    };

var el;
for( el in saveChamp ) {
  if( saveChamp.hasOwnProperty( el ) ) {
    alert( saveChamp[el].type );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want for example retrieve type of my second object in my json. something like saveChamp.[0].type, but it works ^^

Comment: @ClémentAndraud You can also make a list of all 1st level properties in an array first (using the `el` variable in the example) and the take the second element out of that array to retrieve the properties.

Comment: Thanks you, and bnus question, if i want to create a ligne like "champ2": {"type": 3, "size": 4, "null": null} in saveChamp ?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Do you want to modify the old property or add a new one? I don't get it.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud So how about `saveChamp[ 'newProp' ] = { ... }`? If you want to keep the ordering, maybe you're better of with an array instead of an object anyway.